# Why does pickle protocol 2 let me serialise an open file object?

Tags: python, pickle, python-2.x

Consider:

```
>>> import pickle
>>> thing = open('foobar.txt','w')
>>> pickle.dumps(thing)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/pickle.py", line 1366, in dumps
    Pickler(file, protocol).dump(obj)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/pickle.py", line 224, in dump
    self.save(obj)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/pickle.py", line 306, in save
    rv = reduce(self.proto)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/copy_reg.py", line 70, in _reduce_ex
    raise TypeError, "can't pickle %s objects" % base.__name__
TypeError: can't pickle file objects
```

Seems entirely reasonable - of course I can't pickle an open file handle. But:

```
>>> pickle.dumps(thing, 2)
'\x80\x02c__builtin__\nfile\nq\x00)\x81q\x01.'
>>> pickle.loads(pickle.dumps(thing, 2))
<closed file '<uninitialized file>', mode '<uninitialized file>' at 0x7ff3c078>
```

Apparently I can pickle an open file, just not usefully.

Is this deliberate? It was obscuring a bug in my code, where I was wrongly pickling an object that owned a file. Under some conditions, that object also holds a `pyodbc` cursor, with the same result.

I don't see anything in [PEP 307](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0307/) about it. Was it just an oversight, or is there something important going on that I'm missing, that could let me get the exception I want even when pickling using protocol 2?

I'm using Python 2.6.5. I know, I know, but it's what comes with my distribution.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

On the [Python Wiki](http://wiki.python.org/moin/UsingPickle), it says

> You cannot pickle open file objects, network connections, or database connections. When you think about it, it makes sense -- pickle cannot will the connection for file object to exist when you unpickle your object, and the process of creating that connection goes beyond what pickle can automatically do for you. If you really want to pickle something that has an attribute that is causing problems, look at the pickle documentation for `__getstate__`, `__setstate__`, and `__getinitargs__` -- using these you can exclude problematic attributes.

However, I found [this bug report](http://bugs.python.org/issue10180) which indicates that you actually **can** pickle file objects. This does seem to be unintentional. It's been fixed in Python 3.2.

You could see if you could adapt that patch to Python 2.6 if you wanted to prevent it from happening. Otherwise, you just need to be careful what you pickle.

Comment: Aha, from the author of the patch, "I won't backport it since it would risk breaking existing code, although relying on this is really a bug in itself". It *was* a bug in itself, I *wanted* my code to be broken, but fair enough I suppose.

Comment: This sounds like something you should submit to the Python Wiki -- mention that pickle v2 can, in fact, pickle open file objects (but that you shouldn't). Edit: I just added this to the wiki.

Comment: FYI: that fix was released in Python 3.2. A case might be made for backporting to Python 2.7.x by appealing.  Python 2.6 is now closed to all changes except security fixes.

Comment: The "fix" in 3.2 is essentially to have `__reduce__` explicitly throw an error for handles to file-like object. I think it's a poor decision… yes, it's a bad mistake to think pickle should serialize an existing file for you… but serializing a file handle is entirely a different story. If you serialize a file handle, and upon deserialization the file is gone, then the file handle should just deserialize to a "closed" handle. This is another "fix" in 3.x that breaks code going forward from 2.x, and limits python's ability to be robust in parallel. Hence, I think, a poor choice by the authors.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for better behavior, you can use `dill`... which won't serialize file-like objects, but does know how to serialize file handles.  The behavior being that if the file exists, `dill` will point the de-serialized file handle at it... and if the file doesn't exist, then the file handle will be closed.

```
Python 2.7.8 (default, Jul  3 2014, 05:59:29) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple Clang 4.1 ((tags/Apple/clang-421.11.66))] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import dill
>>>        
>>> thing = open('foobar.txt', 'w')
>>> thing
<open file 'foobar.txt', mode 'w' at 0x10e3c2c00>
>>> dill.loads(dill.dumps(thing))
<open file 'foobar.txt', mode 'w' at 0x10e3c2c90>
>>>
```

Get `dill` here: https://github.com/uqfoundation

Comment: Possibly useful to others, but that's the exact opposite of what I wanted at the time. The object I was pickling was a logger, passed (along with some other stuff) over the network. Writing log entries to a file of the same name on the destination wouldn't have helped me, I needed to replace the logger with one that stored messages for later return to the origin. The bug in my code, that this bug in Python obscured, was a case where I neglected to make that replacement. Ofc my bug manifested *reasonably* clearly on the destination, but would have been easier to debug on the origin.

Comment: Understood. In your case, `dill` would have also given you a closed file handle on the other machine, but with a much more digestible handle that `pickle` gives with mode `<uninitialized file>`. The file handle `dill` gives you will give you more sane errors, while the file handle pickle gives you fails in all sorts of unexpected and unique ways.  Hence, my point, is that `dill` gives you "better behavior", even in your case.

Comment: Well, my fear with dill's behaviour would be that the file does exist on the other machine (if I'd run something on that machine previously with the same boring generic logfile), and the log messages get written to it. It's not dill's fault that I want the log messages written locally if and only if the job was started locally, regardless of what files exist on the destination, it's just not what it does.